# "Variable ' ' is not found" when using EXECSCRIPT() command in OLEDB VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-foxpro, oledbcommand

I have a DBF file that consists of more than 10k records and I need to search records using **Visual FoxPro's** `SEEK` command (for faster searching) using vb.net `OleDbCommand`. I tried using `EXECSCRIPT()` to execute VFP command. This is my code :

```
  Using oleCon As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("C:\Users\maymay\Documents\DBF File")
        Try
            oleCon.Open()
            oleCom.Connection = oleCon
            oleTrans = oleCon.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
            oleCom.Transaction = oleTrans

            oleCom.CommandText = "EXECSCRIPT([USE 'C:\Users\maymay\Documents\DBF File\201-file.dbf' ALIAS AA])"
            oleCom.ExecuteNonQuery()

            oleCom.CommandText = "EXECSCRIPT([SELECT AA])"
            oleCom.ExecuteNonQuery()

            oleCom.CommandText = "EXECSCRIPT([SEEK('105345')])"
            oleCom.ExecuteNonQuery()

            oleTrans.Commit()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Try
                oleTrans.Rollback()
                MessageBox.Show("Error occurred. Rollback success")
            Catch rb As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("rollback failed")
            End Try
        End Try
    End Using
```

but the line

```
 oleCom.CommandText = "EXECSCRIPT([USE 'C:\Users\maymay\Documents\DBF File\201-file.dbf' ALIAS AA])"
```

returns an exception

> Variable '     ' is not found.

I tried to remove the `[ ]` and the message becomes

> Function name is missing ).

What am I missing? Or is there any other faster way to seek records in DBF using vb.net OledbCommand? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That line by itself wouldn't return such an error. It is likely you have some index or database event that looks for a variable. You should first try to execute that line from within VFP.

OTOH I wouldn't suggest using Execscript(). It has limited usage and in the code you have, it has no purpose really (if it worked successfully - BTW that code cannot be your real code, it would fail on the first line where you define connection string, you have an invalid connection string).

Anyway, assuming you would do something with that record you could do like this:

```
Using oleCon As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=C:\Users\maymay\Documents\DBF File")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("select * from ('201-file') where yourFieldName = '105345'", oleCon)
    oleCon.Open()
    Dim rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    If rdr.Read() Then
    ' do whatever with rdr
    ' ie:       
    'Console.WriteLine(rdr("FieldName"))
    End If 
    oleCon.Close()
End Using
```

If yourFieldName has an index it would be used. BTW, it is suspicious that you are searching a value like 105345 as if it were a string.